What's the mechanism for docker container to chown of the mapped volume
I have a directory with permissions for user1:
$ ls -la owned-by-u1
drwxr-xr-x 19 u1 u1 4096 Sep  4 16:22 owned-by-u1

$ ls -nla
drwx------ 19 1001 1001 4096 Sep  4 16:22 owned-by-u1

when I map that directory as volume to a postgres container, it changes the owner of the directory to userid 999, which can map to different usernames.
$ ls -la owned-by-u1
drwx------ 19 gitlab-runner u1 4096 Sep  4 16:22 owned-by-u1

$ ls -nla
drwx------ 19  999 1001 4096 Sep  4 16:22 owned-by-u1

I run container like this
docker run -d \
    --name aaa-postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
    -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata \
    -v /home/u1/tt/owned-by-u1:/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata \
    postgres

Can somebody explain the mechanism please?
The dockerd is running as root (not rootless) and UID re-mapping is not enbaled.
If I enable uid re-mapping, the container crashes:
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata': Operation not permitted
find: ‘/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata': Operation not permitted

Which is expected because the root inside is not a real root:
$ docker run \
    --name aaa-postgres \
    --entrypoint "" \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
    -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata \
    -v /home/max/tt/owned-by-u1:/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata \
    postgres cat /proc/self/uid_map

gives this
0     296608      65536

which is in line with /etc/subuid:
$ cat /etc/subuid
dockremap:296608:65536

Here's a bit of docker info:
$ docker context ls
NAME            DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                             ERROR
default *       Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock
desktop-linux   Docker Desktop                            npipe:////./pipe/dockerDesktopLinuxEngine

$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Server: Docker Engine - Community


By default the uids will simply be the same (in some setups, such as rootless docker, some mapping happens, though): the uid you see in the container is the same as the uid outside. Since the host and the container don't share a user database (i.e. /etc/passwd or whatever else is configured) that can map to different (or no) users.

What is your Docker environment (plain Docker on native Linux, Docker Desktop, something else)?  Are you using a rootless mode, and have you enabled uid remapping?

@DavidMaze. thanks for your clarifications, I added those details to the question

@JoachimSauer, yeah, but they are not the same and this is what confuses me. I se that postgress image creates the user 999, maybe this somehow impacts the result?

Just to make it clear: the "uid" is the numerical user id, it is not the username. Try listing the files using ls -nla.

@JoachimSauer, yes, that's correct, I updated the question with the output of ls -nla

I enabled uid re-mapping, and the container crashed b/c it couldn't chown.  I guess before re-mapping it was running as root

There's no mapping of UID's on volume mounts between the docker container and host. But usernames on both are controlled by the /etc/passwd and /etc/group file which is specific to the host and the container (so the username on the host will not match the username for the same uid inside the container).
With rootless mode and user namespaces, the containers can have their user and group id's mapped (following /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid mappings and a specified user to the docker engine). When the containers uid and gid are shifted, that shifted uid and gid will appear in processes on the host and the user trying to access any bind mounts. In this scenario, root in the container is not root on the host, so filesystem operations that try to change ownership of a file on the host will fail the same as if you tried to run them as a random high numbered user outside of a container. If the file on the host is owned by a uid and gid outside of the mapped ranges, I believe it shows up as nobody in the container and any attempt to modify the file will fail since the container user does not have access.
With the postgres example, it is configured to start as root, and modify file permissions as part of the entrypoint. You should avoid host/bind mounts, and instead use a named volume for this scenario. You can see the chown commands to the postgres user in /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh, and the current user and postgres user inside the container with:
# id                                                                                                                                                                                                               
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)                                                                                                                                                                             
# id postgres                                                                                                                                                                                                      
uid=999(postgres) gid=999(postgres) groups=999(postgres),101(ssl-cert)  

Note, with Docker Desktop, there's a VM that the docker engine is running inside of, and that VM has a filesystem driver mounting the host filesystems into the VM in a way that automatically maps uid and gid to the host user when writing files to avoid permission issues.

thanks! Note, with Docker Desktop, there's a VM - do you maybe know if it's something similar to firecracker VM?

and do you maybe know why uid remapping is not enabled by default in docker daemon?

Docker Desktop is based on linuxkit, but the Desktop code itself is not open source (never has been). Enabling user namespaces break host mounts, so changing that default would break existing user workflows.

do you do consulting? we might need some help from an expert

Not currently. It would need to be something significant to come out of retirement and setup a company again.

I see, thanks for the response!
